# Quickblox : how i come to know whether message is sent/received or not?

Tags: android, ios, api, chat, quickblox

Is there any way to find out whether the Quickblox user sent/received message or not , with ANDROID and IOS? I'm using Quickblox ANDROID and IOS SDK.

> There is no method/doc given in QB API documentation.

In Advance Thank You....

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to track 'sent' event - actually you know it always when you sent your message

To track 'received' event - you also can use the same 1-1 Chat messages, but without text body. Just send back a message with 'delivered' status. Your opponent will receive it and mark last sent message as 'delivered'.

Read this doc to better understand this solution http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0184.html

Comment: you will receive message with delivered status

Comment: please read this doc to better understand this solution http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0184.html

Comment: "You don't need to track 'sent' event - actually you know it always when you sent your message" - How? Can you explain? Is there some kind of Result after [[QBChat instance ] sendMessage:message];  ?

Comment: When you send message and it executes without any exception means its successfully sent! Hope you'll understand it! Thanks!

Comment: I think he's asking how to find out if the user has received the messae.